# Android Custom View with many Functions

Tags: android, view, custom-controls, android-custom-view

Is it possible to create a Custom View that will have quite a lot functionality, like downloading some data from the server, parsing it and filling other defined views with this data ?

If it's possible can u give me some references or can u provide some examples.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Check out this library: [Android Smart ImageView](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view)

I typically try to avoid putting too much logic in my views just for organizational and separation concerns, but sometimes it makes sense.

edit: Also, having your views modify views outside of itself doesn't sound like it's the best idea either, unless it's a ViewGroup and you are modifying its children or something.